# .NET Currency To String suppressing leading zeros if value < 1

Tags: .net, string-formatting, currency

I have an issue. Cannot find format which converts decimal to currency string without leading zeros if it is less that 1.

e.g.

```
decimal d = 0.14M;
d.ToString("C"); // Translates to   $0.14  But I need to get  $ .14
```

Are there some special precision specifiers to rich such an effect just calling ToString ?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
string result = String.Format("{0:#.0}", d);
```

source: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Comment: Which will not give you the currency symbol for the current culture.

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal d = 0.14M;
var cs = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;
string result = String.Format(String.Concat("{0:", cs, " #.00}"), d);
// result == "$ .14" if CurrentCulture is "en-US"
```

Comment: This code assumes that the currency symbol always is placed in front of the number separated by space. This is not valid for all cultures, for instance `12.34M.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("ru"))` returns `12,34р.`.

Comment: Hm.. I thought that there is light decision but I see that

Comment: @Martin Liversage I thought this was what the OP wanted. Also, your solution does not have a space between the currency symbol and the decimal number.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti: You solution is probably a fine solution to the question. It just seems slightly weird to extract the currency symbol from the `CurrentCulture` and proceed to use it with the assumption that the cultura was `en-US`. If in fact `CurrentCulture` was `ru` (Russian) the currency symbol would be `р.` (which I believe is a cyrillic letter) and you are then supposed to place it **after** the number **without** a leading space. See my answer to a general (and perhaps overengineered) solution to how that is done.

Comment: @Martin Liversage I see what you mean, your solution is certainly more complete and more correct. By the way, are you sure that it works if the language text direction is right to left?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to take culture into account you need to use the information provided by [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2xdwt6xx.aspx). Below is an extension method to format a decimal as currency but without a leading zero. You can easily change the extension method to a normal method if you don't want to use an extension method.

There is one "shortcut" in the code. It is unable to handle multiple group sizes. I don't think that can be done using a custom number format and the only workable solution will then be to format using `N` and remove any leading `0`.

```
static class DecimalExtensions {

  public static String ToCurrencyFormat(this Decimal value) {
    return ToCurrencyFormat(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
  }

  public static String ToCurrencyFormat(this Decimal value, CultureInfo cultureInfo) {
    return ToCurrencyFormat(value, cultureInfo.NumberFormat);
  }

  public static String ToCurrencyFormat(this Decimal value,
                                        NumberFormatInfo numberFormat) {
    // Assume the CurrencyGroupSizes contains a single element.
    var format =
      "#,"
      + new String('#', numberFormat.CurrencyGroupSizes[0])
      + "."
      + new String('0', numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits);
    var formattedValue = Math.Abs(value).ToString(format, numberFormat);
    if (value >= Decimal.Zero)
      return FormatPositiveCurrency(
        numberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern,
        numberFormat.CurrencySymbol,
        formattedValue
      );
    else
      return FormatNegativeCurrency(
        numberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern,
        numberFormat.CurrencySymbol,
        formattedValue
      );
  }

  static String FormatPositiveCurrency(Int32 pattern, String symbol, String value) {
    switch (pattern) {
      case 0:
        return symbol + value;
      case 1:
        return value + symbol;
      case 2:
        return symbol + " " + value;
      case 3:
        return value + " " + symbol;
      default:
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
  }

  static String FormatNegativeCurrency(Int32 pattern, String symbol, String value) {
    switch (pattern) {
      case 0:
        return "(" + symbol + value + ")";
      case 1:
        return "-" + symbol + value;
      case 2:
        return symbol + "-" + value;
      case 3:
        return symbol + value + "-";
      case 4:
        return "(" + value + symbol + ")";
      case 5:
        return "-" + value + symbol;
      case 6:
        return value + "-" + symbol;
      case 7:
        return value + symbol + "-";
      case 8:
        return "-" + value + " " + symbol;
      case 9:
        return "-" + symbol + " " + value;
      case 10:
        return value + " " + symbol + "-";
      case 11:
        return symbol + " " + value + "-";
      case 12:
        return symbol + " -" + value;
      case 13:
        return value + "- " + symbol;
      case 14:
        return "(" + symbol + " " + value + ")";
      case 15:
        return "(" + value + " " + symbol + ")";
      default:
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
  }

}
```